# StructureMap with WCF?

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, structuremap

Anyone had any luck integrating StructureMap (DI Framework) with WCF?

I can return the default instance in the constructor of my WCF service like this, but obviously it is not ideal.

```
public MemberService()
{
     this.memberRepository = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IMemberRepository>();
}
```

I have seen this (http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/07/29/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf.aspx) but have not had luck setting it up as I think it's incompatible with the latest 2.5+ release of StructureMap.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but ranks at the top of google search still. I just put together a sample, someone might find useful in the future? https://github.com/house9/SampleWcfClientWithStructureMap

Comment: I was able to get WCF and StructureMap to work with the lostechies article you linked to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399072/wcf-service-instantiation-via-ioc-container). What issues did you encounter with the example you provided? Instead of writing the code in the constructor of the service you write it in the [GetInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587089.aspx) method of your [IInstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx) implementation.

Comment: Well, I hit an error where the .With method could not be found at this point .With<DefaultConventionScanner>();. Because I am very new to dependency injection, I did not know where to go from there.  However it may be a case I do not know the namespace that function (or extension) resides in.

Comment: I will take a look at the articles on the post you sent me, thanks. This does look interesting, DIInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider.

Comment: Perhaps I should move to Windsor after seeing Ayende's work @ http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/wcf/index.html

Comment: Once you've pulled all the weeds, it's pretty simple, I have a test project here that's just bare bones wcf and structuremap   https://github.com/billCreativeD/WCF_With_DI